# Another Run Time Error '13': Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to Excel VBA.
I'm triggering several macros depending on the inputs on a particular cell on the work sheet.

I have no problem with the first 2 options.
But everytime I use the third option, which is Delete Row, & everytime I edit a cell or delete a cell, I encounter the error.

The code is below:

```
 Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Set Target = ActiveCell
 If Target.Value = "Fuel Supply" Then (<=Error At This Point)
      Fuel_Heating_Value
 ElseIf Target.Value = "Add Row" Then
      Insert_New_Row
 ElseIf Target.Value = "Delete Row" Then
      Delete_Row
 Else:
 End If
 End Sub
```

The error is always at the third line of the code in the 1st option statement.

The 3rd option code is below:

```
 Sub Delete_Row()
 '
 ' Delete_Row Macro
 '
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     ActiveCell.Select
     ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
     Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
     ActiveCell.Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 12).Select
     ActiveCell.Select
     Selection.Copy
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -11).Select
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
```

Any help to eliminate this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please mark the line that produces the error in your code (`' <- Error here`), your description is a little confusing.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer below, the act of deleting a row triggers another change event and the Worksheet_Change tries to run on top of itself. When it does this, the Target is the row that replaced the deleted row so `Target` is not a single cell. It is a collection of 16,384 cells (an entire row) and you cannot compare a collection of 16,384 cells to a single text string. This is the `Type Mismatch`.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting rows, copy and pasting cells, etc all from a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. You should never modify the worksheet you are on from a Worksheet_Change without disabling events or the actions you take will trigger another event and the Worksheet_Change will try to run on top of itself.

Additionally, I do not know what to make of `Set Target = ActiveCell`. When the Worksheet_Change is triggered, it passes along the address of one or more cells that received a change. You base your conditions on that Target. You do not have to set it to anything. However, you should guard against there being more than a single cell as the Target; your code will throw an error if you try to compare a group of cells to a single text string. Perhaps this is where the error was occurring. Your conditions all depend upon Target being a single cell. I've put exit code if Target is more than one cell because it is pointless to continue if it is plural.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Value = "Fuel Supply" Then
        Fuel_Heating_Value
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Add Row" Then
        Insert_New_Row
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Delete Row" Then
        Delete_Row
    Else:
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now that will not kick another event running on top of the first if anything changes in the worksheet as a result of the Worksheet_Change.

The `Delete_Row` routine can be improved as well but it would help to have a narrative as to what it is trying to accomplish. There are cells selected that are already selected and the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) is thrown around quite a bit.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.